# Parse XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

How do I parse an XML file formatted below using PHP?

I want to store the data from this XML file into my SQL database, but I am having a problem parsing the data.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Data>
<Record>
  <Type>BUILDING</Type> 
  <Building_ID>0000_00</Building_ID> 
  <Facility_Name>0000</Facility_Name> 
  <Facility_Description /> 
  <Status /> 
  <Asset_Owner /> 
  <Address /> 
  <City /> 
  <State /> 
  <Zip /> 
  <Country /> 
  <Mailstops /> 
  <Site_Reference>ML01</Site_Reference> 
</Record>
<Record>
  <Type>SITE</Type> 
  <Building_ID>0001</Building_ID> 
  <Facility_Name>Olympic Base</Facility_Name> 
  <Facility_Description>N/A</Facility_Description> 
  <Status>OWNED</Status> 
  <Asset_Owner>SoCal</Asset_Owner> 
  <Address>N/A</Address> 
  <City>LOS_ANGELES</City> 
  <State>CA</State> 
  <Zip /> 
  <Country>USA</Country> 
  <Mailstops /> 
  <Site_Reference /> 
</Record>
</Data>
```

Here is the code I have tried which is not working:

```
$xmlurl = "http://myurl/data.xml";
$XMLDoc = simplexml_load_file("$xmlurl");

foreach($XMLDoc->Data->Record as $Record)
{
echo (string)$Record->Type;
    echo (string)$Record->Building_ID;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$XMLDoc` is of type [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php).

I think you could change this line:

```
foreach($XMLDoc->Data->Record as $Record)
```

to this line:

```
foreach($XMLDoc->Record as $Record)
```

For example:

```
foreach($XMLDoc->Record as $Record)
{
    echo (string)$Record->Type;
    echo (string)$Record->Building_ID;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Will result in:

```
BUILDING0000_00
SITE0001
```

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem.